# React-native on IOS: cannot adjust current top of stack beyond available views

Tags: ios, react-native

When writing a component, I suddenly got a very strange error in my IOS simulator: "cannot adjust current top of stack beyond available views"

Here is my code:

```
var Badge = require('./badge');
var Separator = require('./helpers/seperator');
var View = React.View;
var StyleSheet = React.StyleSheet;
var ScrollView = React.ScrollView;
var Text = React.Text;

var Profile = React.createClass({
    _getRowTitle: function (userInfo, item) {
        item = item.replace('_', ' ');
        return item[0] ? item[0].toUpperCase() + item.slice(1) : item;
    },

    render: function () {
        var userInfo = this.props.userInfo;
        var topicArr = ['followers', 'following', 'email', 'bio'];
        var list = topicArr.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <View key={index}>
                        <View>
                            <Text> {this._getRowTitle(userInfo, item)} </Text>
                            <Text> {userInfo[item]} </Text>
                        </View>
                        <Seperator />
                    </View>
                );
            }
        });

        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
                <Badge userInfo={this.props.userInfo} />
                {list}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
});
```

Does anyone know where this error is coming from?

Comment: did you solve it? i am facing the same issue ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out this happens in React-Native when you misspell the component name. My imported class, `Separator` should have been spelled `Seperator` and my linter and the build system did not catch the error. Apparently if you try to use an object that is undefined in React-native, this is the error you get!

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the observation you made, this error can occur more generally whenever you reference or misspell a name. It is not limited to only Component names.

for example, if you create a `styles` object to hold your styles, but accidentally refer to it as `style`, then you will also see this error thrown.