# "Cannot Adjust current top of stack beyond available views" - Error only when Debug in Chrome is turned Off

Tags: react-native

I'm having an issue where I get the above error, but only when on my hardware ios device, or emulator debugging is turned off. IF it is on, it works fine in the ios 6 simulator.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007008/react-native-on-ios-cannot-adjust-current-top-of-stack-beyond-available-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Interestingly, React-Native seems to use a different version of Javascript when the debugger is on. I was trying to use a ES5 function for formatting text as currency, and it worked fine as long as the debugger (and browser) are on. However, turning this off forces react-native to use their specific javascript core which did not support that javascript function.

I fixed it by using a different function. The error should be more specifc to explain you are doing something illegal.