# reactNative listView xcode error Cannot adjust current top of stack beyond available views

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

i want to know  what circumstances occur this kind of mistake in a rn listView demo???????
[left is Simulator error, the right is xcode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0KCa.jpg)

[but if i Comment out the sentence，it works well but notting appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FusMI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you return a wrong data. Check the output of your function (in the set state) and try again.

The problem isn't new:
[React-native on IOS: cannot adjust current top of stack beyond available views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007008/react-native-on-ios-cannot-adjust-current-top-of-stack-beyond-available-views)

Comment: you are right,Can't find the problem, want to commit suicide by hanging，you saved me

Comment: Hope you're joking about the suicide 