# React Native: Exception thrown while executing UI block: put reactNavSuperviewLink back

Tags: react-native

After I upgraded React Native from 0.14 to 0.26 for my IOS app I am keep getting this exception:

*** Assertion failure in -RCTNavigator reactSuperview, /path_to_app/node_modules/react-native/React/Views/RCTNavigator.m:461
2016-05-20 20:55:43.217 [error][tid:main][RCTUIManager.m:1100] Exception thrown while executing UI block: put reactNavSuperviewLink back

Before the upgrade I did not have this problem. I am using NavigatorIOS.

Any advice on how to fix it or what to even look at while debugging is greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve this @mark?

Comment: @ChrisEdwards just posted my solution, hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

When I was trying to solve this problem, in React Native docs there was a statement, that they are aware about million bugs of NavigatorIOS but are no longer working on the component as facebook doesn't use it internally, and they pointed [to this library](https://github.com/wix/react-native-controllers) as an alternative for better NavigatorIOS. (back then this library only provided replacement for NavigatorIOS, now they added few more gems) I was going to use it, but then I read that their Navigator [does not synchronize between JS and native](https://github.com/wix/react-native-controllers#user-content-what-sacrifices-did-we-make), that's why instead of using the library I made a decision to stop forcing synchronization between JS and native in React's NavigatorIOS, which solved the problem.

I ended up commenting out `RCTAssert(!_bridge.isValid || self.superview != nil, @"put reactNavSuperviewLink back");` in node_modules/react-native/React/Views/RCTNavigator.m.

I know it is a work around, but since React Native approved [this library](https://github.com/wix/react-native-controllers), and many people are happy with, I feel like mirroring what they implemented(not implemented) should be somewhat safe. At least it worked for my app and no further bugs occurred.

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your answer. Would you mind editing your post to include the relevant code, rather than a screenshot? It's not very easy for others to copy code from an image ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okay no, any answer that includes "Comment out this part of the library" is wrong.  Plain and simple.

The issue you are having is a from having you navigatorIOS set up wrong.  Make sure you don't have any nested/looping navigators and clean up your code.

Don't rush through it or you will find more issues like this... remember react native is YOUNG and things will break if you are reckless

Comment: I agree that commenting out the line that causing the error is often dangerous, but I added an explanation why I think in this case it can be ok.  Yet you are wrong that this issue can only come from wrongly setting up NavigatorIOS, NavigatorIOS is extremely buggy, and often causing problems on it's on.

Comment: Your first sentence makes a claim, and offers no justification except "Plain and simple."  It shouldn't be _that_ hard to make the case that this is not a great idea, but if it's so "plain and simple", then shouldn't you be able to give a supporting argument, instead of just making an assertion?  And rather than the simplistic claim that it's "wrong", why not enumerate the drawbacks to that approach.  That would be a valuable contribution.

Answer (score 1):

After commenting out the line as indicated in the follow up post by @Mark, I ended up getting a different error `Cannot adjust current top of stack beyond available views`. Reading up on another thread ([React-native on IOS: cannot adjust current top of stack beyond available views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007008/react-native-on-ios-cannot-adjust-current-top-of-stack-beyond-available-views)) it turns out I wasn't properly importing the component that was being used. Although this turned out to be a "user error" on my behalf, perhaps this might explain other accounts of this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue when using a [TabBarIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios.html) without children. I fixed it by adding an empty view.

Before: `<TabBarIOS></TabBarIOS>`

After: `<TabBarIOS><View /></TabBarIOS>`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue occurred because of previously cached navigator data in the iPhone simulator.

If cached data is the problem switching to another simulator device or deleting the app within the simulator will solve the problem.